# mysqldump does not dump my schema or data

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

mysqldump is giving me a file that includes no schema or data.  In researching this, I see there has been a change in MySQL and I must either use the --no-tablespaces flag, or I need to grant a process privilege to the user.  However, granting a process privilege is considered insecure, and use of the --no-tablespaces flag does not address the problem -- the resulting dump file is still nearly empty, aside from a few annotations.

Once upon a time, mysqldump was easy to use and it always worked.  No doubt I could have that same experience again, if I knew how to use it.  So what am I missing?  How can I get mysqldump to actually dump the database into a file, like in the days of old?

The user/password I specify in my mysqldump command is one that can connect to the database for all the CRUD purposes of my application, so I'm puzzled as to why the same user can't mysqldump the database.

The MySQL version is 8.0.33.

Comment: Not the answer you are looking for but have you tried `mysql-shell util dumpInstance` instead of the old `mysqldump`. `mysql-shell` can use multiple threads while `mysqldump` is single threaded among other better features it has over the old utility.

Comment: By the way, adding your full `mysqldump` command and the existing privileges of the mysql user taking the backup might help.

Comment: Can you provide the exact command you issued - it's been a while but there are definitely forms of `mysqldump` which will give you the `schema or data`!

Answer (score 0):

(Not an answer, but some research in the changelogs)

----- 2023-04-18 8.0.33 General Availability -- -- -----

Using [--single-transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction) with mysqldump version 8.0.32 required either the [RELOAD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_reload) or [FLUSH_TABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_flush-tables) privilege. This requirement now applies only when both [gtid_mode=ON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-gtids.html#sysvar_gtid_mode) (default OFF) and with [--set-gtid-purged = ON|AUTO](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_set-gtid-purged) (default AUTO). (Bug #109685, Bug #109701, Bug #34993824, Bug #34998910, Bug #35020512)
References: This issue is a regression of: Bug #105761, Bug #33630199.

----- 2023-01-17 8.0.32 General Availability -- -- -----

Data and GTIDs backed up by mysqldump were inconsistent when the options [--single-transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction) and [--set-gtid-purged=ON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_set-gtid-purged) were both used. This was because, between the start of the transaction by mysqldump and the fetching of GTID_EXECUTED, GTIDs on the server could have increased already. With this fix, a [FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flush.html#flush-tables-with-read-lock) is performed before fetching GTID_EXECUTED, to ensure that its value is consistent with the snapshot taken by mysqldump.

Our thanks to Marcelo Altmann for the contribution.

Limitation: This fix adds a requirement for the [RELOAD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_reload) privilege when using [--single-transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction) to execute FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK; the MySQL team is investigating a solution. (Bug #33630199, Bug #105761)

----- 2021-01-18 8.0.23 General Availability & 2021-01-18 5.7.33 General Availability -- -- -----

When invoked with the [--all-databases](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_all-databases) option, mysqldump now dumps the mysql database first, so that when the dump file is reloaded, any accounts named in the DEFINER clause of other objects will already have been created. (Bug #32141046)